# int *array = new int[n]; what is this function actually doing?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I am confused about how to create a dynamic defined array:

```
 int *array = new int[n];
```

I have no idea what this is doing.  I can tell it's creating a pointer named array that's pointing to a new object/array int?  Would someone care to explain?

Comment: I thought this was a basic question, but maybe modern c++ books/courses don't explain anymore the keyword `new`, I actually kinda like that...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*new* allocates an amount of memory needed to store the object/array that you request. In this case n numbers of int.

The pointer will then store the address to this block of memory.

But be careful, this allocated block of memory will not be freed until you tell it so by writing

```
delete [] array;
```

Comment: Could I suggest that you edit this to say something like "but you should instead do `std::vector<int> array(5);` as this is the correct way to create such an object in C++".

Comment: ... because, for example, if the function returns early (e.g. an exception is thrown), then the `delete` will not get called. Basically, normal developers should never explicitly type `new` (nor `delete`) in modern C++.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: The modern exception-safe version of this would be: `std::unique_ptr<int[]> array{new int[n]};`  `std::vector` is quite a bit more than just an exception-safe version of the code shown.

Comment: My point isn't so much that `vector` is identical to `int [n]`. If we assume that we want an exception-safe answer to the original question, we really only have two options: `unique_ptr<int[]>` and `vector<int>`. The former may be 'purer', but I'm sure most of us (including you perhaps?) would use `vector` to solve the actual problem the questioner if facing now. We don't know the full context of their current programming assignment - but it's a fair bet that `vector` is the solution most of us would use.

Answer (score 14):

```
int *array = new int[n];
```

It declares a pointer to a dynamic array of type `int` and size `n`.

A little more detailed answer: `new` allocates memory of size equal to `sizeof(int) * n` bytes  and return the memory which is stored by the variable `array`. Also, since the memory is dynamically allocated using `new`, you should deallocate it manually by writing (when you don't need anymore, of course):

```
delete []array;
```

Otherwise, your program will leak memory of at least `sizeof(int) * n` bytes (possibly more, depending on the allocation strategy used by the implementation).

Comment: No, it doesn't initialise the memory with zero. And `array` is actually a pointer to an `int`, not to an array. And the memory leak will be at least the size you mentioned, but it could easily be greater.

Comment: @Nawaz The reference for the C++ Language is the C++ Standard, not some bit of code that you have written that by chance happens to support your assertion.

Comment: @unapersson: Alright. Then see §5.3.4/15 which starts with this >> *A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:[...]*.

Comment: @unapersson: *[..] but it could easily be greater.*...Why?  Any reference?

Comment: s5.3.4/15 states "if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value". Section 8.5, which specifies the default init rules, states for an array without explicit init, each element is default-init'ed. The default-init for an int (with no constructor obviously) is "no initialisation is performed". So int arrays are indeterminate. So I don't think your argument is correct, @Nawaz.

Comment: @paxdiablo and @unapersson: Oops... I read `non-POD` and `POD`.. they should capitalize `non` also. :D... Anyway, I edited the post.

Comment: @Nawaz Memory allocators do not usually allocate the exact size you ask for - they allocate in multiples of some convenient size. So if you asked ffor `new int[3]` you might get 32 bytes (for example) rather than the 12 bytes  you might expect on  a platform where `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Comment: @unapersson: That makes sense. But it would be good if you could give the reference so that I can know it from concrete source (i.e the Standard).

Comment: @Nawaz The standard has nothing to say about how memory allocation should be implemented.

Comment: @unapersson, while it may well _allocate_ more memory than that, you cannot use any of the extra without invoking undefined behaviour. Hence, as far as you're concerned, you should assume you only have _exactly_ what you asked for. The only time you'll run into problems is if you do a lot of small allocations so that the wastage is high.

Comment: @paxdiablo: +1 for this point **if you do a lot of small allocations so that the wastage is high.**.... thanks :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo My original point was about the amount of memory that Nawaz says is leaked, not about the legality or otherwise of accessing that memory.

Comment: @unapersson: Aah, I see now what you were getting at. Edited to fix, hope you don't mind, Nawaz.

Answer (score 13):

The statement basically does the following:

1. Creates a integer array of 'n' elements
2. Allocates the memory in HEAP memory of the process as you are using *new* operator to create the pointer
3. Returns a valid address (if the memory allocation for the required size if available at the  point of execution of this statement)

Answer (score 2):

It allocates space on the heap equal to an integer array of size N,
and returns a pointer to it, which is assigned to int* type pointer called "array"

Answer (score 2):

The [`new` operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) is allocating space for a block of `n` integers and assigning the memory address of that block to the `int*` variable `array`.

The general form of new as it applies to one-dimensional arrays appears as follows:

```
array_var = new Type[desired_size];
```

Answer (score 1):

It allocates that much space according to the value of n and pointer will point to the array i.e the 1st element of array

```
int *array = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, pointers and arrays are (almost) equivalent.
`int *a; a[0];` will return `*a`, and `a[1];` will return `*(a + 1)`

But array can't change the pointer it points to while pointer can.

`new int[n]` will allocate some spaces for the "array"

Answer (score 0):

As of C++11, the memory-safe way to do this (still using a similar construction) is with [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> array(new int[n]);
```

This creates a smart pointer to a memory block large enough for `n` integers that automatically deletes itself when it goes out of scope. This automatic clean-up is important because it avoids the scenario where your code quits early and never reaches your `delete [] array;` statement.

Another (probably preferred) option would be to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you need an array capable of dynamic resizing. This is good when you need an unknown amount of space, but it has some disadvantages (non-constant time to add/delete an element). You could create an array and add elements to it with something like:

```
std::vector<int> array;
array.push_back(1);  // adds 1 to end of array
array.push_back(2);  // adds 2 to end of array
// array now contains elements [1, 2]
```