# What is meant by the statement new employee *[num] in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I came across this statement in a book.

```
new employee *[num];
```

where employee has already been declared as struct employee
and num is an int;

this is on the right hand side of = operator on the statement.

So, what is meant by that statment?
The book doesn't offer any explanation of the said statement.

Comment: It allocates a new employee* array of size num. The return value is never caught.

Comment: IMO this is an example of why the * should go with the rest of the type.

Comment: This is creating an array of `num` pointers to `employee`

Comment: why the downvotes for a legitimate question? maybe not all of us are pure c++ pros...

Comment: @xmoex Thanks for some support. The book doesn't give any explanation for the declaration. Only usage in middle of a program.

Comment: @xmoex Doesn't have to do with the lack of c++ knowledge shown in this question, but it's incomplete in form and badly asked. It's unlikely the answer helps anyone else than the OP.

Comment: @xmoex: also some basic google search will help the OP find the answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which is disturbing since all the _possible_ duplicates I've  found thus far are even less clear.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Then at least the title should be edited to be something more meaningful in relation to the question.

Comment: i don't want to initiate a chat about this but i think what one could find via google or elsewhere depends on how familiar you are with a certain topic. i think it's a perfectly legal question for so and from my point of view it's not at all "badly asked". +1 solidarity upvote...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ... then maybe helping in improving the question would be a better idea than just downvoting...

Comment: @xmoex Improvement is primarily left to the OP. I'm willing to retract my close/down vote if the question is made clearer and better.

Comment: Okay I came here after googling. I know that to search for answer is faster than to post question and then to wait for someone to answer it. But I could not find any relevant answer or for that matter any kind of related post.

Comment: The question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776529/int-array-new-intn-what-is-this-function-actually-doing is slightly different but the answers address your query.

Comment: I came across that, and readily understood that, but here the * was creating problem for me. Now I understand that we are creating array of pointers at run-time. In that question array of int was being created. After seeing the answers here now I am able to find the similarity between the two. But I was all confused before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will allocate a memory required to hold `num` number of pointers to `employee` on the free store.

e.g:

```
employee** a = new employee* [2]; // 2 pointers on the heap
```

heap:

```
address a (e.g. 0x97a0008): pointer1 to employee

address a + 1 ( 0x97a000c): pointer2 to employee
```

Side note: you use `delete[]` on arrays so you can delete above with `delete[] a` **BUT** you will have to loop first through all entries if you have allocated memory for them so it have to be freed before you loose the pointer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13477214/1141471

Comment: Okay, I got confused with the *. So here we are using new to initialize pointer at runtime. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Think it is like this,

```
typedef employee* TEmployee;
TEmployee * ap = new TEmployee[10];
```

So, it allocates memory for dynamic array of size 10 type TEmployee (not employee). It is as simple as,

```
int * aip = new int[10];
```

TEmployee itself is a pointer type to employee.