# What's the difference between new and new[] in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

I am trying to figure out the C++ memory allocation mechanism. I understand the difference between `operator new()` and the `new` expression.

But as I found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/), the prototypes of `operator new()` and `operator new[]()` are almost identical, and the default implementations of `operator new[]()` should simply invoke the corresponding version of `operator new()`.

My questions are:

1. If we can simply use `operator new()` functions to allocate any size of memory and use the memory as an array, what is the purpose of `operator new[]()`?
2. I tried this piece of code:

   ```
   struct MyClass {
       MyClass() { cout << this << "::MyClass()" << endl;}
       ~MyClass() { cout << this << "::~MyClass()" << endl;}
   };

   int main()
   {
       MyClass *ptr = (MyClass *)::operator new[]( sizeof( MyClass) * 3);
       new (ptr) MyClass;
       new (ptr+1) MyClass;
       new (ptr+2) MyClass;
       delete[] ptr;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   It printed out following messages before it crashed:

   ```
   0x562ecf758e70::MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e71::MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e72::MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e90::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e8f::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e8e::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e8d::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e8c::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e8b::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e8a::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e89::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e88::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e87::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e86::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e85::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e84::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e83::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e82::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e81::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e80::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e7f::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e7e::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e7d::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e7c::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e7b::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e7a::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e79::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e78::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e77::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e76::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e75::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e74::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e73::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e72::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e71::~MyClass()
   0x562ecf758e70::~MyClass()
   *** Error in `/home/alec/.cpp-run/1/a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000562ecf758e68 ***
   ```

   Why did `delete[]` try to destruct 30 objects which didn't exist and was out of the memory allocated by `operator new[]()`?
   Also, why did it crash?

Comment: You say there's no single article/blog post on that subject on the web to date?

Comment: Read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What _are_ you doing? My suggestion is for you to not worry about this, stop using pointers, and just use normal objects. Use `MyClass c` if you want a single object, and `std::vector<MyClass> v` if you want a container. Guessing at code is not going to improve you, just start reeeaaaally simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int \*array = new int\[n\]; what is this function actually doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776529/int-array-new-intn-what-is-this-function-actually-doing)

Comment: Also: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: The reason for the three constructor calls should be obvious - the three `new` expressions each invoke the constructor.    The `delete [] ptr` in your code has undefined behaviour since `ptr` is not the result of `new []` expression.    There is more to the working of a `new []` expression (e.g. `x = new X [5]`) then calling `operator new []()`.

Answer (score 1):

On question 1). Even though the default versions of `operator new()` and `operator new[]()` do the same thing, a program can override `operator new[]` and make if behave differently. It's a customization point.

On Part 2).

There is a footnote in the standard saying

> 218) It is not the direct responsibility of `operator new[]` or `operator delete[]` to note the repetition count or element size of
>   the array. Those operations are performed elsewhere in the array `new` and `delete` expressions. The array `new` expression, may, however, increase the `size` argument to `operator new[]` to obtain space to store supplemental information.

So while `new Myclass[3]` must store the `3` somewhere so that `delete[]`can find it, apparently `::operator new[]( sizeof( MyClass) * 3)` does not. At least not in the place where `delete[]` expects it.

So it seems like `delete[]` happens to find some other number and goes on to destroy non-existent objects until it hits a wall.